# Why starting an application with a key binder, it does not tile?

Tags: lua, awesome-wm, tiling

I have a problem with tiling applications in awesome-wm.

I set up some key biners in the rc.lua:

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Control" },            "f",     function () awful.util.spawn("firefox") end,
             {description = "firefox", group = "client"}),
             
awful.key({ modkey, "Control" },            "z",     function () awful.util.spawn("/opt/zotero/./zotero") end,
             {description = "zotero", group = "applications"}),
```

If I start the application with the key binding, it does not tile in tiling mode.

However, if I start it from the run menu, it tiles perfectly

Are there any specifications I have to include in the awful.util.spawn instruction to allow tiling?

I also tried to use awful.spawn instead of awful.util.spawn, but it behaves at the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution: the above reported code starts the applications in a maximized mode. To avoiid that I added a condition "maximized = false" as shown below:

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Control" },            "f",     function () awful.util.spawn("firefox", {maximized = false} ) end,
              {description = "firefox", group = "applications"}), 
              
  awful.key({ modkey, "Control" },            "z",     function () awful.util.spawn("/opt/zotero/./zotero", {maximized = false}) end,
              {description = "zotero", group = "applications"}),
```